# How to show inheritance in a UML textual specification of classes?

Tags: uml

How can I show inheritance in an UML textual specification of classes like this one:

```
**class** ...
    **inv**: ...;
    **features**:


**operations**:
    **public** ... (in ...: ...; inout ...: ...): ... {...}
    **comment**: "..."
    **pre**: ...;
    **post**: ...;
    public ...


**end** ...
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no such standard defined in the UML specs. So you are likely free to invent your own convention - and document it along with your model.

Comment: There are some popular textual representations around such as plantuml or to a lesser extent mermaid. There is also a standardized  xml representation.  if you're using a tool, then you need to add some context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML 2.5.1 states on p. 102:

> Members that are inherited by a Classifier may be shown on a diagram of that Classifier by prepending a caret ’^’

So you can use that in a textual representation (where ever yours came from).